# How to check a projects vue.js version?

Tags: vue.js

I use **Ubuntu 16.04** and I'd like to know how I check the `vue.js` **version** used by my project.

How do I do that?

Comment: Depends how you're doing things - look in your `package.json` file, perhaps? How is the OS relevant?

Comment: Run `npm list vue`

Comment: I didn't know if the OS would be relevant or not. But I could check that out on the `package.json`. Thanks @jonrsharpe!

Comment: Are you running Vue.js client side or server side?

Comment: Server side. @JamesAMohler

Comment: From a console, you should also be able to get that info by `Vue.version`

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Let's summarize the solutions from @jonrsharpe, @JamesAMohler and @MartinCalvert for friends looking for a quick answer.

1. Run `npm list vue` (or `npm list --depth=0 | grep vue` to exclude packages' dependencies). It is [a common way](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) to check npm package's version in the terminal.
2. Of course, you can also check vuejs's version by browsing package.json (or use command like `less package.json | grep vue`).
3. Use `Vue.version` during the runtime. It is a [global API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-version) provided in vue.js.

Answer (score 42):

If you have the Vue.js Chrome dev tool extension installed and your application is built in development mode you can simply open up the Chrome Dev Tools and use the Vue extension tab. It is clearly displays the Vue version for the project at the top (see below)

[image]

Comment: FYI, if you only see the V logo without version, make sure you make the Vue dev window wider so it gets room to include the text without wrapping.

Comment: its actually showing me a different version than from package.json. So what now?

Answer (score 33):

Please simply try type `npm v vue` in terminal to check the version of Vue.js

Comment: its diving version of vue installed in system not the version which project is using

Answer (score 18):

This is what worked for me:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

alert(`Vue version : ${Vue.version}`);
```

Comment: Also works on the result of createApp from Vue 3. `import { version } from 'vue'` is a great way to check without running a foul of importing createApp when it doesn't exist. Beware of vite dependency prebundling when doing this.

Answer (score 13):

There are few ways to check vue version:

1. `npm v vue` run this on the terminal
2. Check `package.json`, code will be something like this

```js
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

3. If you have vue dev tools installed then go to the Vue tab and you should be able to see the version there.
   [image]

**Note:** If you use `vue --version` - this will check vue cli version, not Vue version

Answer (score 11):

If you want to check the current version of **Vue** installed in your machine use `vue --version`

If you want to check the **Vue** installed on the project then use `npm list | grep vue@`

Comment: Thanks, @VenkataSaiKatepalli, the second one was quite useful to me. The first command may be to check the vue cli version (I think).

Answer (score 7):

It can be checked from package.json file. Inside dependencies block you can see vue and its version.

"dependencies": {
"vue": "^2.6.11"
}

Answer (score 2):

if you have installed vue dev tools extension like I recommend, you can just press `ctrl` + `shift` + `i` at least in the firefox and then look with vue extension [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlztX.png)

You can also just use `npm v vue` in command prompt, you cant use `vue --version` becausue this checks what Vue CLI you have

Answer (score 2):

For the solution of in-app version showing for vue version 3+.
As @ray-foss mentioned: I am only able to use

```
import {version} from "vue";
console.log('Vue version', version);
```

The way using `import Vue from 'vue'` does not work anymore (for me).

Answer (score 0):

You can only use **npm v vue** in CLI/ in Terminal, you can't use **vue --version**, it shows error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53k9H.png)

Answer (score -3):

You can also type to check the Vuejs version `vue --version`

Comment: This command checks the version of Vue CLI, not the version of Vue.js.