# Which version of VueJs am I currently using?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, version

How to print, display or find your current VueJS version?

All I can see is in my package.json object with dependencies where it says `^2.5.13`

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "current"? The version installed in `node_modules`? Check its package.json or `npm ls`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check my vue.js version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019022/how-do-i-check-my-vue-js-version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vue instance holds information like, in your case the version. [Vue version](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-version)

Usage: Import vue on the file you want to use it

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

and then just do

```
Vue.version
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `npm list vue` to show the installed version of a module (in this case vue)

Answer (score 2):

[Vue.version](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-version) Shows your current vue version.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using [Vue.js devtools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) which simply shows the version in the heading of the console tab. This way you don't have to fiddle with source code (that might end up in production).

Answer (score 1):

For vue 3 you can access the version like this

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

...

vueVersion() {
  const app = getCurrentInstance().appContext.app;
  return app.version;
}
```